# character encoding issue while reading email using java mail api

Tags: jakarta-mail, encode

Hi I am reading emil's from a mailbox using Java mail Api.
For an email ,The from Address has Chinese characters and looks as below

```
(krishna 国际快 <12139@ty.com> ).
```

After reading the email , When I get the from Address from message using `message.getFromAddress();`
The  from address is some thing like below

```
?utf-8?Q?Kris=EF=BC=88=E4=BF=9E=E7=94=9F=EF=BC=89?= <12139@ty.com>
```

How can I get the original from address.

Comment: If the From header is properly encoded, JavaMail should decode it for you.  What does the raw From header look like (msg.getHeader("From", null))?  From the above, it looks like it's missing an initial "=" that starts the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The email address encoding issue while reading the email from a mail box  is fixed.

```
StringBuffer sbFrom =null;
sbFrom = new StringBuffer();
Address[] in = msg.getFrom();

                for (Address address : in) {                    
                    System.out.println("FROM: " + address.toString());

                    sbFrom.append(address.toString());
                }
```

I created two solutions for this . Please find them below.

Solution 1:

Created a regular expression and  checking the regular expression , If  email address matches the regular expression  then we decode the email address.

Please check the code below.

```
String ENCODED_PART_REGEX_PATTERN="=\\?([^?]+)\\?([^?]+)\\?([^?]+)\\?=";
                 Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(ENCODED_PART_REGEX_PATTERN);
                 Matcher m =pattern.matcher(sbFrom.toString());
                 if(m.find()){
                     System.out.println("FROM: " +MimeUtility.decodeWord( sbFrom.toString()));
                 }else{

               System.out.println("FROM: " + sbFrom.toString());
               }
```

Solution 2: Written a method which decodes the  given email address. If we get javax.mail.internet.ParseException while decoding  then it means the email Address do not have any encoded characters , so we return normal string.
Please observe the below method.

```
 public String decodeAddress(String emailId) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
       String string = "";
       try{
           string =  MimeUtility.decodeWord(emailId);
       }catch(ParseException e){
           System.out.println("ParseException occured so return the same string");
           string =emailId; 

       }
       return string;
   }
```